# what the meaning of #!/usr/bin/php -q

Tags: centos7, scripting, php7

I look at some php script in centos,I notice there is `#!/usr/bin/php -q`

What is the meaning of this option? because I cannot see it in `php --help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage for [php(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/php) describes this option, and it is also documented in the PHP Manual; [Command line options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

> | Option | Long Option | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `-q` | `--no-header` | Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only). |

Answer (score 0):

The line itself is known as a "[shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang#:%7E:text=usr%2Fbin%2Fpython3-,Starting%20a%20Script%20With%20%23!,such%20as%20%2Fbin%2Fbash.)" or, more formally, an [Interpreter Directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
It tells the shell which interpreter (and options) to use to process [the rest of] the script.